# Removing my razor tag prevents me from using my viewmodel in my post

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

If I have a razor element that looks like this inside a html.beginform() on my vie

> @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Listing.LocationType)

but I have to replace the razor syntax and use html with bootstrap because I want a more custom drop down menu then the one that razor gives me.

ex. I want a group of buttons with a nested drop down menu

```
<div id="LocationTypeSelector" class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default spaceType">Home</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default spaceType">Apartment</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default spaceType">Studio</button>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Other
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a class="spaceType">Park</a></li>
                            <li><a class="spaceType">Beach</a></li>
                            <li><a class="spaceType">Field</a></li>
                            <li><a class="spaceType">BackYard</a></li>
                            <li><a class="spaceType">FrontYard</a></li>
                            <li><a class="spaceType">Other</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
</div>
```

so now I'm not setting my viewmodel property 'LocationType' and I'm forced to set some values with jQuery/javascript and on form submit use jQuery's ajax or post and submit that way, which would eliminate my html.beginform() and viewmodel entirely! Am I missing something here!? Or not doing something correctly??

Comment: Do you mean something like in [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/creating-radio-buttons-using-bootstrap-and-mvc)?

Comment: Actually my scenario is a little more complex then just a radio button or button group. My group of buttons have a nested drop down in it. Update above. Additionally, how does this article show how to set the viewmodel data?